# Java Hour to Minutes Simple conversion

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, int, typeconverter

I am working on a simple program which given 2 times (1015 and 1025 and 0925 and 1010) will return the time difference in minutes between them.

So

**1015 and 1025 -> 10 minutes difference**

Comment: Your example times do not contain the `:` separator that your code is looking for.

Comment: (If indeed you have the times as contiguous digits, I'd convert to int, use divide/modulo by 100 to split into hours and minutes, then multiply hours by 60 and add the two values back together to get comparable minutes.)

Comment: (Note that this -- `String[] str_array = "FirstTimeString1:FirstTimeString2".split(":");` -- does not substitute FirstTimeString1 and FirstTimeString2 into the string, since the entire string is a literal.)

Comment: Java code, not like C, must live inside a class, without `public class CLASS-NAME { .. Code here .. }` it just won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple math formula will give you the answer:

```
((10*60 +10) - (9*60 + 25))
```

So now all you need to do is:

1. Split the 4 digits string into 2 group numbers.
2. Calculate the minutes by Converting the hours into minutes and add them into the minutes new number.
3. Subtract the bigger number from the smaller one.

Walla!

**Code example:**

```
public class goFile {
    public static int SubtractTime(String number1, String number2)
    {
        return Math.abs(ConvertTimeToMinutes(number2) - ConvertTimeToMinutes(number1));
    }

    public static int ConvertTimeToMinutes(String number)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, 2))*60 + Integer.parseInt(number.substring(2, 4));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SubtractTime("0925", "1010"));
        System.out.println(SubtractTime("1015", "1025"));
    }
}
```

Comment: :D this is what I did in the first code, but I'm getting a lot of compilation errors..no idea why :/

Comment: If you're going to represent times as strings (no, no no!) at a minimum follow standard conventions like separating hours and minutes by a `:`...

Comment: @dimo414, I used the user input, because I can not assume I know nothing about her restriction or if she can manipulate the input that is given to her. If she would give any more details many things would be different. Additionally, to use a whole new Library just for 1 simple function, especially if she only needs it once is a overkill and a waste of time/code + program overhead. If I want to just cut a bread once I won't use a light saber.

Comment: Both fair points, but we should also be encouraging best practices and educating; nothing in the question speaks to "needing" to represent times as non-delimited string, and as doing so will cause more problems, we should call that out.  Additionally, even if it's a one-off application, Time-math can quickly get more complicated than anticipated (the Java Calendar utils demonstrate that painfully well).  Your answer is certainly "correct" and presumably addresses the user's issue, but that doesn't make it a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to work with times and dates is to use a time/date utility library.  Attempting to do the math manually yourself is a good recipe to shoot yourself in the foot.

Your two best choices are [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), if you aren't running Java 8, or the [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package if you are.

I'll give you an example with Joda-Time, since *I'm* not running Java 8 sadly, but I'll update this answer with a Java 8 example as well  when I have a chance.  They're functionally very similar (`java.time` was largely based on Joda-Time).

```
LocalTime nineTwentyFive = new LocalTime(9, 25);
LocalTime tenTen = new LocalTime(10, 10);
LocalTime tenFifteen = new LocalTime(10, 15);
LocalTime tenTwentyFive = new LocalTime(10, 25);

System.out.println(Minutes.minutesBetween(tenFifteen, tenTwentyFive).getMinutes());
System.out.println(Minutes.minutesBetween(nineTwentyFive, tenTen).getMinutes());
```

> ```
> 10
> 45
> ```

Both libraries are highly tested and popular, meaning you can trust them to do the right thing out of the box, even in edge cases you don't anticipate.  Don't re-implement this behavior yourself.